# MySQL Query not fetching the right results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web forum whereby only some selected users are allowed access to it i.e they must have `$_SEESION['username']` on.

Now on the profile page - which looks like this

```
http://127.0.0.1/mysite/profile.php?username=john
```

I want to display either an upload button or an edit profile button,
depending on if they have an image uploaded.

I'm checking to see if $_GET is set, first then if not it redirects to
the homepage:

```
if(isset($_GET['username'])) {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);

$profile = mysql_query(SELECT *
                       FROM forum
                       WHERE username = '$username') or DIE(mysql_error());

                       $row = mysql_fetch_array($profile);

                    echo"
                    Name : $row[name];
                   Country : $row[country];

    if($_GET['username'] == $_SESSION['username'] && $row['imagepath'] == '') {
   echo "Upload Button";
}
else {
      echo"Edit Button";
}
}
```

Upload Button is shown on the screen, when actually there's an image
path specified.

Please where I'm I going wrong.

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` functions in your code. These functions are no longer maintained and are [being deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead, you should use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't know which to use? [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should help.

Comment: I like how you let the script DIE in upper case. Other than that, there's really not much information as to how this question can be answered. Right back atcha: *"Where are you going wrong?"*

Comment: To use $_SESSION you will need to set session_start();

Comment: you're sure that `imagepath` is the correct field name ?

Comment: Your quotes are off in the echo" Name: $row[name]; Country : $row[country]; -----No end quotes  Also you should use single quote marks inside the [] brackets. e.g. $row['name'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put double quotes around your mysql_query-parameter. I copied your code and that was my solution.

You echo too much by the way. It should be as the following code.

```
echo "Name: ".$row['name'];
echo "Country: ".$row['country'];

if($_GET['username'] == $_SESSION['username'] && $row['imagepath'] == '') {
    echo "Upload Button";
}
else {
    echo"Edit Button";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `mysql_query("QUERY HERE")`, else it won't work at all.
- `$row['name']`, `$row['country']`: you need to put the names between quote marks.
- `echo 'Text'`. You didn't close the quotation marks.
- `empty($row['imagepath'])`. There's a function for it, so use it.

If the above corrections still don't work, try echo-ing all the variables you need: `$_GET['username']`, `$_POST['username']`, `$row['imagepath']`. Perhaps PHP cannot read them.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed all the syntax errors from here you could starting debugging:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['username'] ) ) {
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['username'] );

  $profile = mysql_query( "SELECT *
    FROM forum
    WHERE username = '$username'" ) or DIE( mysql_error() );

  $row = mysql_fetch_array( $profile );

  echo "Name : " . $row['name'];
  echo "Country : ". $row['country'];

  if ( $_GET['username'] == $_SESSION['username'] && $row['imagepath'] == '' ) {
    echo "Upload Button";
  } 
  else {
    echo"Edit Button";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why down voted? Took the effort to clean the code .. Very nice guys!

Comment: It's not actually an answer though.